# rake migrate aborted trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, migrate

I am following a tutorial, but this tutorial is using Rails 2.0.
However, I am using Rails 4.0.
I guess this difference makes a trouble when doing    rake migrate?

[photos/db/migrate/20130722034245_create_photos.rb]

```
class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :photos do |t|

    t.timestamps
  end
end

def self.up
  create_table :photos do |photo|
    photo.column "filename", :string
  end
end

def self.down
    drop_table :photos
  end
end
```

[On my terminal]

```
seodongju@Seoui-MacBook-Pro ~/Desktop/Projects/photos$ rake migrate
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Solved..
'rake migrate' was old version command. :/
do this.. 'rake db:create'

Answer (score 1):

```
 rake db:migrate
```

not

```
 rake migrate.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do

```
rake db:migrate
```

and not just `rake migrate`.  Also have a look at the documentation under the heading **Running Migrations** in the following link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html